# Adjacency Matrix and Adjacency List Time Complexity

Tags: algorithm, graph

For adjacency matrix, I'm confused on why Are adjacent(u,v) would be O(1) and incident edges(u) be O(n) (I think its because even if the matrix is not filled, algorithm still has to traverse all the matrices).

For adjacency list, I'm confused on why Are Adjacent(u,v) time complexity is O(min{degree(u),degree(v)} because wouldn't that be the bast case scenario?

Answer (score 1):

**I am assuming you are talking about UNDIRECTED graph**

so your intuition for matrices is correct

1. `adjacent(u,v)` is just a constant time lookup in the matrix at `u`-th row and `v`-th column
2. `edges(u)` is linear because you have to check with every other vertex if they are connected, or in the matrix, you have to go through the whole `u`-th row. So it will be O(n). Note that `n` is number of vertices and not whole size of matrix, we generally write this as O(V)

Now for the adjacency list, the complexity of the `adjacent(u,v)` minimum of the degrees because **YOU** can choose to iterate on the vertex that has a minimum degree.

if the graph is **undirected** `adjacent(u,v) == adjacent(v,u)`, so it doesn't matter whose adjacency list you traverse. So you can choose to traverse the one with the minimum degree.